# Storybook Fails after NPM install / Issue with Babel or Gatsby?

Tags: npm, jestjs, babeljs, gatsby, storybook

I've been running storybook successfully, but recently npm installed jest, which caused my entire package.json to update and storybook to break. Not sure where to start (issue with babel or gatsby?), but here is the error for my terminal when I try to run storybook:

> ```js
> > 
> >     ERROR in ./node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/navigation.js
> >     Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './redirects.json' in '/Users/zmason/Documents/code/resourcehub-components/node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir'
> >      @ ./node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/navigation.js 12:17-44
> >      @ ./node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/page-renderer.js
> >      @ ./node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/public-page-renderer-prod.js
> >      @ ./node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/public-page-renderer.js
> >      @ ./node_modules/gatsby/cache-dir/gatsby-browser-entry.js
> >      @ ./src/components/Card/LinkCard.js
> >      @ ./stories/index.stories.js
> >      @ ./.storybook/config.js
> >      @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/server/config/polyfills.js
> > ./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/server/config/globals.js
> > (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true ./.storybook/config.js
> >     Child html-webpack-plugin for "iframe.html":
> >               Asset    Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
> >         iframe.html  569 kB       0
> >            [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/server/iframe.html.ejs
> > 1.16 kB {0} [built]
> >            [1] ./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
> >            [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
> >            [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
> >     Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
> >              Asset    Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
> >         index.html  569 kB       0
> >            [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/@storybook/react/dist/server/index.html.ejs
> > 1.7 kB {0} [built]
> >            [1] ./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
> >            [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
> >            [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
> > 
> >
> ```

Any help would be huge!

Comment: nevermind! just did an npm audit fix and it resolved it ! !